# Cannot search Managed properties displays nothing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search, people-search

I've created managed properties and they have values from User Profile Service application, I've ran a full crawl and Profile Service application Sync and I can view the values on my display template. But for some reason I cannot search by Managed properties that I've created. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to flag the properties as Searchable (for free text results) and Queryable (to use them explicitly in a query MyProperty:Foo or MyProperty=Foo).